# Evaluating tbats multiseasonal time series (R forecast package)

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, cross-validation, tbats

I'm using the `TBATS` model of the `forecast` package (version 8.0) with Google Analytics data, to forecast web trafic containing multiseasonal effects (`msts`). Before asking my questions, I'll explain the methodology I used.

## Methodology

#### Data

I have two year of daily data that contains two columns like these :

```
date           sessions
2015-01-01     2667
2015-01-02     3542
2015-01-03     2383
2015-01-04     2772
2015-01-05     7797
2015-01-06     7599
```

I created a `data.frame` with the Google Anlytics API, that includes the data until the end of February 2017, with the intention of using it as a train set.

I created another `data.frame` with with the month of March 2017, with the intention of using it as a test set.

#### Model

I did a multiseasonal time series, to take into account the daily, monthly and annual seasonality :

```
y.msts <- msts(gadata$sessions,seasonal.periods=c(7,30.4, 365.25))

fit <- tbats(y.msts, use.box.cox=NULL, use.parallel=TRUE, num.cores = NULL, 
             use.trend=NULL, use.damped.trend=NULL, use.arma.errors=TRUE,                           
             model=NULL)
```

#### Results

Here is the time series components, residuals and forecast I obtained :

```
components <- tbats.components(fit)
plot(components)

checkresiduals(fit)

fc <- forecast(fit)
plot(fc)
```

[image]

With the `accuracy` function of the `forecast` package, I obtained the following results with the training set :

```
accuracy(fc)

             ME       RMSE     MAE       MPE      MAPE     MASE       ACF1
Training set 99.63043 1008.008 672.8444 -0.372223 10.10871 0.3125927 -0.06044894
```

## Questions

1. How to include a test set in the `accuracy` function? Is the `accuracy` function the best way to evaluate a forecasting model?
2. What is the best way to create a test set without changing the date in the code every time (for example, by always taking the last month as a test set)?
3. Any recommandation to improve the overall methodology from a statistical point of view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Predict on the test set using `forecast`, before calculate the accuracy.
2. Using the last date of training data, plus 30. You can try the `lubridate`package, it process the date and times very comfortable.
3. First, try the seasonal test, whether there is multiple seasonal effects. 
   Second, try different parameters for model or different models, compared the predictions on test set.
   After that, do the residual test, whether it is random.